# SQL Constraint only if column has a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to add a unique constraint to a sql table but only if the column has a specific value. In my case, I have Geographic IDs and Status as fields. The IDs can have multiple status but there should only be one Current (C) status per ID. Is there a way to involve a where clause to have unique values only in the case of C values?

I tried adding a UNIQUE CONSTAINT as well as a filtered index, to no avail.

Comment: Being that a filtered index is the right answer, this goes to show that questions should always include the code that was attempted.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can create filtered indexes, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Demo (
  GeographicID int,
  [Status] char(1)
);
create unique index IXUF_Demo_GeographicID_Current
  on dbo.Demo (GeographicID)
  where [Status]='C';
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'A');
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'A');
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'B');
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'B');
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'C'); --Succeeds
insert dbo.Demo (GeographicID, [Status]) values (1, 'C'); --Fails
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Apologies, I should have included my code in the initial post. I had used the following, which didn't work:   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CREC] ON [dbo].[TABLE]
(
 [GEOID] ASC,
 [Status] ASC
)
WHERE ([STATUS]='C')